# How to pass session values to different methods in play and slick?

Tags: playframework, slick, playframework-2.3

So I have a validation method located in one of my play form model objects:

```
  def validateForm(form:Form[forms.RegisterForm.registerFormData]) = {
    val name = form("name").value.get
    val test = TableQuery[UsersTable].filter(_.name === name).firstOption.get.name
    if (test == something) {
      blah
    } else {
      blah
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the implementation of it in the controller:

```
  def registerSubmit = DBAction { implicit rs =>
    RegisterForm.registerForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => {
        BadRequest(views.html.user.register(formWithErrors))
      },
      formData => {
        val valForm = RegisterForm.validateForm(RegisterForm.registerForm.fill(formData))
        if(valForm.hasErrors) {
          BadRequest(views.html.user.register(valForm))
        } else {
          stuff
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

How can I pass the slick session to the validateForm method? At the moment I can't query for form validation because the queries have no session to use.

I know some of these references don't look the prettiest but they've been changed since this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just request a session

```
def validateForm(form:Form[forms.RegisterForm.registerFormData])(implicit session: Session)
```

there is an implicit conversion from your `rs` value to a slick session, which will be applied.